# Can anyone tell what might had gone wrong with the transaction below?

Tags: transactions, nonce

May I know what does this transaction mean? I am running this inside my private node. Running the same transaction repeatedly none stop. Sending on average 10 transactions / sec. So I had to keep track of the nonce.

But suddenly the transaction below just stopped and refused to process. Query transaction receipt just return null.

May I know what might had gone wrong?

Did I skipped one nonce? How can I tell if I had really skipped one nonce?

```
> eth.getTransaction("0xb992cfa1e25268de903d54196c1efa1908fcaf900a304db2bde14c1315461dca")
{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0xc8caa71c16299b40b8579742a27ee53162886040",
  gas: 160000,
  gasPrice: 2600000000,
  hash: "0xb992cfa1e25268de903d54196c1efa1908fcaf900a304db2bde14c1315461dca",
  input: "0x2a281eb70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011",
  nonce: 2049,
  r: "0x88741393e597de552cf28563c7a601fd7c4f43111144f010d29011aac82756e9",
  s: "0x6becf956d4d622ca4cbe68381dfd6f614aa75fe6ffc6c2081dc725b79ee51819",
  to: "0x9ee0ff1b31fb2587d55f3a6726cb6d653d4b6615",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x47",
  value: 0
}
```

Comment: What does `eth.getTransactionCount("0xc8caa71c16299b40b8579742a27ee53162886040")` returns? Perhaps your node skiped a nonce?

Comment: Yes. Finally I realized what had gone wrong. The getTransactionCount returns little endian whereas Windows uses Big endian byte array. I had skipped.

Answer (score 1):

The eth.getTransaction() details that you have posted shows
**blockNumber: null**.

It implies that the transaction with the transaction hash **"0xb992cfa1e25268de903d54196c1efa1908fcaf900a304db2bde14c1315461dca"** has not been mined into a block or you could say added into a block.

If you are using Ethereum's PoW as a consensus algorithm then it takes 15 seconds to mine a block, and as you said 10 transactions on an average, it is clear that you tried fetching details of a transaction that was not yet mined.

Comment: It had been there for more than 10 minutes. That is why I feel strange. This problem gone when I tried to limit the rate of transaction to more than 15sec. If I send many transactions in less than 15 sec, this problem will come back again. There might have some threading issues.